# How to develop for Azure Sphere on macOS?

Tags: azure-sphere

The [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-sphere/get-started/) state that developing for the [Azure Sphere](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Azure-Sphere-MT3620-Development-Kit-EU-Version-p-3134.html) device requires

> A PC running Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later

and

> Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, Professional, or Community, version 15.7 or later

Is there a way to develop for the device on macOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no VS code support for Mac OS. You will need to use Window 10 Anniversary update or later.

You can open a feature request for the Azure Sphere team to enable Mac OS support [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915433-azure-sphere/suggestions/38746939-add-mac-support).

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915433-azure-sphere/suggestions/35567668-add-mac-vs-code-support

Comment: There is a new User Feedback entry to separate VS Code support request from Mac support since they were bundled together up vote Mac support request here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915433-azure-sphere/suggestions/38746939-add-mac-support